# creating several bitmaps and binding them to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

i need to create a bitmap and to load it as a texture( create a bitmap in program, make some drawings and then bind it to texture)

loading bitmap from file system is like this

```
    private int images[] = {
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.six,
            R.drawable.five,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four,
};
```

my loadTexture functoin is looks like this

```
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        // Generate texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(images.length, textures, 0);
        for (int image = 0; image < images.length; image++) {
            // bind texture pointer 
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[image]);
            // create nearest filtered texture
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            // different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
            // get the texture from the Android resource directory
            {
                InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(images[image]);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    // BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        // Always clear and close
                        is.close();
                        is = null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
                // use Android GLUtils to specify a 2D texture image from our bitmap
                GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
                // cleanup
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
        }
```

and finaly I have a funcion which draw a canvas and save it in bitmap. (now it's only one) I want to know how can I apply that created bitmap to images array.

```
public Bitmap onDraw( Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

   Bitmap one = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
   Canvas c = new Canvas(one);
   canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 256, 256, paint);

   paint.setTextSize(40);
   paint.setTextScaleX(1.f);
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   canvas.drawText("Your text", 30, 40, paint);
   paint.setColor(Color.RED);
return one;

}
```

how can I load bitmaps to int[] array?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](http://www.41post.com/4396/programming/android-bitmap-to-integer-array)?

Comment: no, i mean, that i can load several bitmaps to array, and use it in my LoadGLTexture function.